# In tcl how can I group signals and put them in a particular category

Tags: string, scripting, tcl

In tcl how can I group signals and put them in a particular category
I have a few signals

```
    ahb_hdata
    apb_pdata_out
    axi_reps_n
    apb_req_n
    ahb_reset_n
    apb_pwrite
    ahb_haddr
    axi_ready_in
    axi_trans
```

I wanted to group the signals in this format

```
ahb:         apb:             axi:
 ahb_hdata      apb_pdata_out   axi_trans
 ahb_reset_n    apb_pwrite      axi_reps_n
 ahb_haddr      apb_req_n       axi_ready_in
```

So far I was able to search whether substring is present or not,
But here I have many substrings that are to be searched and had to group them, I didn't how to group them and put them under a particular category

```
set string "ahb_hdata, apb_pdata_out, axi_reps_n, apb_req_n, ahb_reset_n, apb_pwrite, 
ahb_haddr, axi_ready_in, axi_trans "

set substring "ahb"
  if {[string first $substring $string] != -1} {
puts "$substring"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping everything is easy with [`dict`s](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.html) - use the prefix as key and each value is a list of names. It's formatting the output into columns that's a little tricky, but since `lindex` with an index out of range just returns an empty string, still fairly clean - calculate the maximum length of the lists of common prefixes, and iterate up to that, extracting the Nth value of each list in turn:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

proc group_signals {signals} {
    set sigs [dict create]
    set lengths [dict create]

    foreach sig $signals {
        if {[regexp {^[^_]+} $sig prefix]} {
            dict lappend sigs $prefix $sig
            dict incr lengths $prefix
        }
    }

    # Header                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    puts "[join [dict keys $sigs] ":\t"]:"

    set maxlen [::tcl::mathfunc::max {*}[dict values $lengths]]
    for {set n 0} {$n < $maxlen} {incr n} {
        set line {}
        dict for {_ list} $sigs {
            lappend line [lindex $list $n]
        }
        puts [join $line \t]
    }
}

group_signals {
    ahb_hdata
    apb_pdata_out
    axi_reps_n
    apb_req_n
    ahb_reset_n
    apb_pwrite
    ahb_haddr
    axi_ready_in
    axi_trans
}
```

Comment: Heh, I came up with almost the exact same solution, except I was a bit more terse: `for {set n 0} {$n < $maxlen} {incr n} {puts [join [lmap list [dict values $sigs] {lindex $list $n}] \t]}`